# SQL query to get values which are not repeated by a column

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

I have a table like

```
User id   Status
 XXX        Y
 XXX        N
 YYY        N
 ZZZ        Y
 ZZZ        Y
```

Now I need to select those users which are present only once in the table along with the status value. The required output:

```
User id   Status
 YYY        N
```

I tried with

```
SELECT userid,status from table GROUP BY userid,status having count(userid)=1
```

but it gives output as

```
User id   Status
 XXX        Y
 XXX        N
 YYY        N
```

Comment: i think because you are also grouping by status the having part is counting each status count separately. So basically im saying try your query again without  `status` in your `group by`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT userid,status from table where userid IN
(SELECT userid from table GROUP BY userid having count(userid)=1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT userid, status
FROM table
GROUP BY userid, status
HAVING (COUNT(userid) = 1)
```

Comment: it is the same query I posted?

Comment: The () brackets were not used correctly, did you try it ?

Comment: Sorry about the delay, I did not read the question well enough here you go ..
SELECT userid, status
FROM table where userid = (select userid from table group by userid having (count(userid) = 1)